# Display <> in a pre html tag

Tags: html

How do you display things like  or anything in <> brackets in a html pre tags.

I tried

```
<pre><stdin></pre>
```

but I get a blank?

Comment: Please do search on google before posting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `&lt;` and `&gt;`  for < and > even in `<pre>`

Answer (score 4):

```
<pre>&lt;stdin&gt;</pre>
```